# How to define a custom Rectangle class driven from the Rectangle class?

Tags: wpf, derived-class, rectangles

I have already coded a custom made `RichTextBox` class in WPF. but I need to have a tiny Rectangle on the top-left corner of this `RichTextBox`, in order that I can use it as a dragging handle whenever I want to drag the `RichTextBox`.
So I started like this:

```
public class DragHandleRegtangle : Shape
    {
        public double len = 5;
        public double wid = 5;

        public DragHandleRegtangle()
        {
           //what should be here exactly, anyway? 
        }
    }
//Here goes my custom RichTextBox
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox
...
```

But I have no idea how I can specify the width/length/fill color of it, and the most important it's position related to the `RichTextBox` (which is exactly zero-zero related to RichTextBox's anchor point - i.e: top left corner of it)

And the first error I've got so far is :

> 'ResizableRichTextBox.DragHandleRegtangle' does not implement
>   inherited abstract member
>   'System.Windows.Shapes.Shape.DefiningGeometry.get'

I'd appreciate if someone could help me define my rectangle and resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

write this to your code

```
   protected override System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry
   {
      //your code
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much !
Inside the piece of code you wrote, I have this:  
`get { 
 throw new NotImplementedException(); }`
It resolved the error, yet I still don't have the rectangle in the canvas ! I mean it's not rendered or something.
And what do I do to set the width/height/bg color, etc. of this Rectangle ?

Comment: I have never inherited a UI control so I can not help you further. But while you need a Rectangle why not to use the Rectangle class?

Answer (score 1):

The WPF framework has a class that does what you are looking for.  The `Thumb` class represents a control that lets the *user drag and resize controls*.  It is commonly used when making custom controls.
[MSDN Docs for Thumb class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms612587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Here's how to instantiate a thumb and wire up some drag handlers.

```
private void SetupThumb () {
  // the Thumb ...represents a control that lets the user drag and resize controls."
  var t = new Thumb();
  t.Width = t.Height = 20;
  t.DragStarted += new DragStartedEventHandler(ThumbDragStarted);
  t.DragCompleted += new DragCompletedEventHandler(ThumbDragCompleted);
  t.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(t_DragDelta);
  Canvas.SetLeft(t, 0);
  Canvas.SetTop(t, 0);
  mainCanvas.Children.Add(t);
}

private void ThumbDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
  Thumb t = (Thumb)sender;
  t.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

private void ThumbDragCompleted(object sender,      DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  Thumb t = (Thumb)sender;
  t.Cursor = null;
}
void t_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
  var item = sender as Thumb;

  if (item != null)
  {
    double left = Canvas.GetLeft(item);
    double top = Canvas.GetTop(item);

    Canvas.SetLeft(item, left + e.HorizontalChange);
    Canvas.SetTop(item, top + e.VerticalChange);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !  
I'm gonna test it soon ;)